# Способ кэширования json на php

Tags: json, кэширование

Нужно вытягивать json в базу mysql и при следующем запросе - проверять: если в базе уже есть содержимое - то запрос по json не делать.

Я реализовал так:

```
$nn=mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($nn > 0)
{}
else { 
$url = file_get_contents('site.ru/test/');
$yummy = json_decode($url, true);
$mysq_title = $yummy['parse']['title'];
$mysq_text = $yummy['parse']['text']['*'];    
$mysq_pageid = $yummy['parse']['pageid'];
$mysq_segment = $segment[2];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages(title, text, pageid, segment) VALUES ('$mysq_title', '$mysq_text', '$mysq_pageid', '$mysq_segment')");
}
```

Но я не уверен, что парсинг через json не осуществляется. Подскажите, правильно ли реализовано? И если нет - то как лучше сделать?

Comment: А смысл от базы, если `json` есть? Сохраняйте `json` у себя на сервере, парсите в массив, для более лучшей производительности можно загнать в `MCached` и тогда не `json_decode` не `mysql` не нужно будет дергать постоянно, а кешь поставить к примеру раз в какое-то время перепроверять `json` файлик на изменение.

Comment: тут проект на несколько миллионов страниц и дергать постоянно json не смогу, нужно лить именно в базу. Скажите пожалуйста не как лучше, а сработает ли данная схема, которую я привел выше? Или же там все равно выполняется запрос к json?

Comment: Странный подход - у вас же постоянно будет дергаться и файл и база, считай, что в двойне нагрузка. Иначе, как вы будете узнавать, что в `json`, что-то изменилось и нужно записать в базу?

Comment: почему файл будет дергаться? Он по сути 1 раз же дергается и заносится содержимое в базу, затем при загрузке страницы - данные берутся из базы. Мне не нужно проверять изменения, нужно один раз загрузить и все.

Comment: Как вы узнаете, что в `json`, что-то изменилось и нужно изменить или записать в базу? На вашем примере ободранного куска кода, ничего не понятно и `mysql_*` давно пора выкинуть.  К тому-же, если в базе не окажется, чего-то, будет дергать файл, а если будут ложные данные, будет постоянно обращаться к файлу и дергать базу с ложными сработками и нотисов с ошибками будет до кучи, а там и взлом не далеко.

Comment: Мне не нужно проверять в json изменения. Нужно один раз вытянуть от туда инфу и потом показывать постоянно, не дергая каждый раз json. Поэтому и в базу пишу

Comment: Еще разочек, в базе не оказалось записи, что будет? А будет у нас дергать файл, а если в файле не будет то, что мы хотим, что будет? А будет пустая запись в базу. ПРОФИТ!!!